# Node.js and johnny-five issue

Tags: arduino, node.js

Not sure if this is the right place to ask this but here goes. So I am working on a project where i control a rc car from my web browser. I am using the raspberry pi (Rev B) as the webserver and socket.io host and an arduino mega 2560 with a motor shield  Previously i was able to do this with leds, but now i want to control motors.  The problem i have is that the webpage is not being loaded while the app is running.  When i run the code below, my browser just continuously loads the page and nothing comes up.  Im using node.js and the johnny-five library. I can control the motors with no issues if i plug pin commands straight into REPL or straight into the code.

```
var five = require("johnny-five"),
board = new five.Board({
  port: "/dev/ttyACM0"
});

board.on("ready", function() {
  var motor;

  motor = new five.Motor({
    pins: {
      pwm: 9,
      dir: 8,
      cdir: 11
    }
  });

var app = require('http').createServer(handler);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
var fs = require('fs');

//http port
app.listen(8080);

//Log favicon requests and serve html page to clients
function handler (req, res) {
  if (req.url == "/favicon.ico"){   // handle requests for favicon.ico
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/x-icon'} );
  res.end();
  console.log('favicon requested');
  return;
  }
  fs.readFile('motor_test.html',    // load html file
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}

//Here is Socket.io Logic
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('forward', function(data) {
        if (data == 'forward') {
            motor.forward;
        }
        else if (data == 'stop'){
            motor.stop;
        }
    });
    socket.on('reverse', function(data){
        if (data == 'reverse'){
            motor.reverse;
        }
        else if (data == 'stop'){
            motor.stop;
        }
    });
});

});
```

Just to point out, i recently tried putting everything inside the `board.on("ready",` function.  I have tried taking all the http and socket.io stuff out of this and still get the same result.  It looks like everything is working right when i run it.  In the console it shows that it sucessfully connected to my arduino. And there is definitely no issues with my html. Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Possibly a hoisting problem. You may want to try opening the HTML first. Then use a switch case to deal with the XHR requests. What address are you accessing the webserver from?